# Check for Empty on Array of String

Tags: c, gdb

I've declared the following array of strings:
char *arrayIndices[100] = {0};

I do a comparison with recp->ut_line which is declared as:

```
struct utmp {
....
char ut_line[32]
}
```

using:

```
strcmp(arrayIndices[i], (char*)recp->ut_line))
```

This gives me a segmentation error.
I've also tried these in gdb:

```
if (arrayIndices[i] == NULL)
if (arrayIndices[i] == "\0")
```

The second one turns up false.  arrayIndices[i] shows a value of 0x0 when printed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use apostrophes, not quotes, here:

`if (arrayIndices[i] == '\0')`

Comment: But `arrayIndices[i]` is a `char *`. Does it make sense to compare a `char *` and a character literal ?

Answer (score 1):

The `strcmp` fails because there's no memory allocated to `arrayIndices[i]`. You can *check for empty* like so:

```
if (!arrayIndices[i] || !arrayIndices[i][0])
   /* Empty. */
```

Comment: The first one worked.  On the second check, it wasn't able to access memory.  I'm thinking that "if (arrayIndices[i] == 0)" might be the best way to do this.

Comment: @user994165 `arrayIndices[i] == NULL` is completely equivalent to `!arrayIndices[i]`.

Comment: For some reason in gdb when I did a test "p (arrayIndices[i] == NULL)" it gave me a 'No symbol "NULL" in current context'.  But actually running it works.  In gdb I was able to use "p (arrayIndices[i] = '\0'" though.

Answer (score 0):

@cnicutar's answer is correct, but looks a bit too succint for me.  I'd like to write

```
if ( NULL == arrayIndices[i] || 0 == strlen(arrayIndices[i]) )
    /* empty */
```

You're worrying if `strlen` might take too much CPU time?  Never worry about it,

- http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

  > Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

On the other hand **@StilesCrisis's answer is WRONG**.  I would downvote it if I had enough reputation!  Actually I'm surprised to realize that it even compiles.  (Maybe due to `'\0' == 0 == NULL` on the most platforms)

Off topic: you may be interested in `String#blank?` method provided by Ruby on Rails :-)